# In Bash, sourcing a file affects associative arrays declared in it. Why?

Tags: bash

The test case is as follows:

*sourced-file.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -A MY_MAP=();

function C_function() {
  MY_MAP[foo]="bar";
}
```

1. First test

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

function A_function() {
  source sourced-file.sh
  B_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}    
function B_function() {
  C_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}
A_function;
```

Running `./test.sh` prints:

```
declare -A MY_MAP=([foo]="bar" )
declare -A MY_MAP=([foo]="bar" )
```

2. Second test

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

function A_function() {
  source sourced-file.sh
  B_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}    
function B_function() {
  source sourced-file.sh
  C_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}
A_function;
```

Running `./test.sh` now prints:

```
declare -A MY_MAP=([foo]="bar" )
declare -A MY_MAP=()
```

3. third test

*test.sh*

```
#!/bin/bash

function A_function() {
  B_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}    
function B_function() {
  source sourced-file.sh
  C_function;
  declare -p MY_MAP;
}
A_function;
```

Running `./test.sh` now prints:

```
declare -A MY_MAP=([foo]="bar" )
./test.sh: line 5: declare: MY_MAP: not found
```

I'm using `bash 4.4.23`, and I'd like to understand this behavior. Could someone shed light on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used inside a function without `-g`, `declare` declares a `local` variable. Sourcing `declare` from a function works the same way, i.e. it creates a local variable. Adding `-g` would not empty the array in case 2 and would recognise the array in case 3.

Answer (score 2):

> When used in a function, `declare` makes each *name* local, as with the `local` command, unless the `-g` option is used.

- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare

When you `source` within a function, the `declare`d variables are local to that function (and visible in functions/subshells that you invoke from that function).

a demo:

```
a() { local x=10; echo "a before: $x"; b; echo "a after: $x"; }
b() { local x=20; echo "b before $x"; c; echo "b after: $x"; }
c() { echo "c before: $x"; x=30; echo "c after: $x"; }
x=5
a
echo $x
```

outputs

```
a before: 10
b before 20
c before: 20
c after: 30
b after: 30
a after: 10
5
```

Without testing it, if you `declare -gA MY_MAP` in the sourced filed, I expect you'll have different results.